# Magneto - block orders from specific state

Tags: magento, geolocation, ip-geolocation

I'm looking to restrict the ability for orders in Magento to specific states, or rather, block a specific state.

I'm selling products that I don't want local competition to be able to easily purchase.

It'd be even cooler to use some form of geo location to display a banner on the site, saying we don't allow orders from your state only if the IP seems to come from that state.

Or maybe a hack would be to use a geo location, and css hide the add to cart button if the IP was based from specific state?

any suggestions!
Thanks!

edit: I've been able to get the state like this:
but how to say "if state=X, then load this css file, which could hide add to cart, display a banner, etc."

```
<?php 
function getClientIP(){
  if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
  } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
  } else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
 }
  return $ip;
}

$ipaddress = getClientIP();

function ip_details($ip) {
  $json = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/geo");
  $details = json_decode($json, true);
  return $details;
}

$details = ip_details($ipaddress);
echo $details['region'];

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm against hiding a CTA button using css, what if someone just inspects the page and unhides it. I suggest you to do something similar to this.

//considering you can fetch the location using your php logic in your server side already.

```
$details = ip_details($ipaddress);
$loc = $details['region'];
blockedList = array();      //maintain the list of blocked states here.
if(in_array($loc,$blockedList){
    //display banner, hide add-to-cart button
} else {
    //display add-to-cart button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This magento extension wasn't easy to find for some reason, but it works!

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/regions-manager.html